# Web browser rendering errors in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox, icons

This is a weird problem I've run into while using Ubuntu 18.04. A lot of the things in the web are somehow misplaced. The browser I'm talking about is Firefox (latest), though the issue (with the icon shift, haven't tested the cursor) persists on Chrome.

For example, the cursor in the Stack Overflow question editor and the GitHub online file editor seems much shorter than it should be.

[image: short cursor]

A plain textarea seems fine, though

[image: textarea]

Then the icons have this problem. Here's how the icons in the GitHub Gist Preview look like. As you can see, they are shifted down from the center.

[image: icon shift]

At last, the icons in the Firefox Inspector are also shifted down (which seems completely unrelated to any CSS rendering issues). In the following screenshot, the "+" and the color picker are shifted down.

[image: inspector]

The issue was first encountered on an upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04, then I did a fresh reinstall of 18.04, but the problem remains.

What could cause this? Has anyone encountered anything similar?

---

Edit about the modifications I've made to my GNOME Shell:

- Install Roboto fonts (`sudo apt install fonts-roboto-hinted`)
- Install Materia theme (Shell and GTK+)
- Install Numix-Circle icons
- Install Materia GDM theme (more about it [here](https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme/wiki/GDM-Theme))

Undoing all those modifications didn't seem to fix the bugs.

My Ubuntu is installed on a physical machine (not a VM), I am using X11, but the problem persists on Wayland.

---

Another edit: I just tried to live boot a fresh Ubuntu 18.04, the inspector icons were offset even there.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 both, as it seems

Comment: i assume you use x11 in your ubuntu 18. Did you installed different fonts or did you made any change in the in themes? Do you get any serious  error mmessages in you dmesg ?

Comment: @abu_bua yes, I've installed Roboto using the following command: `sudo apt install fonts-roboto-hinted`. I am using X11, but as I mentioned above, the problem persists in Wayland. Not sure about how to sift through the `dmesg` output to find errors

Comment: you can get an error output using the command `dmesg --level=err,warn` . btw: do run a virtual machine like virtualbox or is your ubuntu machine a real one?

Comment: @abu_bua no, nothing relevant in dmesg. Check out the edit

Comment: Themes can be dangerous! They change your fonts (incl. properties like scale, ...) and even the icons. I'd a case with no standard icons available for instance. Try to  change the theme and shell to default for test purposes and restart your gnome-shell (log out/in *or* press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and then <kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>) . I would also contact the *gdm* developers on the forum.

Comment: @abu_bua yeah, I've tried resetting the themes. Moreover, I've tried live booting a fresh Ubuntu. The issue is still there

Comment: you didn't answered a question - do you run ubuntu on  a virtual box machine or on real hw!

Comment: @abu_bua I did, it's in the edit. I run a real machine

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change **fonts** settings in the tweaks menu.

Install tweaks with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
```

and invoke it.

Under the **fonts** menu change hinting to **Slight** and the **Antialiasing** to **Subpixel** or whatever is the best for your graphics.

Comment: Nope, tried different settings, that didn't work